# Not sideloading data on index routes only with custom serializers in ActiveModel::Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to figure out for a `/recipes` index route in Ember, how I can opt not to sideload extra JSON data that's unneeded for that particular view, but sideload that data in the individual recipe routes.

The way it's working right now, Rails is returning the JSON payload as I want:

`/recipes.json`

```
{
  "recipes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Scrambled Eggs"
    }
  ]
}
```

`/recipes/1.json`

```
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "substep_ids": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    }
  ],
  "substeps": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    }
  ],
  "recipe": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Scrambled Eggs",
    "step_ids": [
      1
    ]
  }
}
```

If I go to `/recipes` in my Ember app, it will render

- Scrambled Eggs
- Hash Browns

But if I click on the `link-to` then I won't see the appropriate steps and substeps that would be sideloaded when requesting the API for `/recipes/:recipe_id`. If I manually refresh that page, the data is successfully sideloaded.

Is there a way to do what I want?

On the Rails side:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all.includes(steps: [:substeps])
    render json: @recipes, each_serializer: ShortRecipeSerializer
  end

  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.includes(:steps => [:substeps]).find(params[:id])
    render json: @recipe
  end

end

class RecipeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true

  has_many :steps

  attributes :id, :title
end

class ShortRecipeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title
end
```

And on the Ember side:

```
Recipe = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
  steps: DS.hasMany('step', {async: true})

Step = DS.Model.extend
  substeps: DS.hasMany('substep', {async: true})
  recipe: DS.belongsTo('recipe')

Substep = DS.Model.extend
  step: DS.belongsTo('step')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work, sorry my coffee script is not very good but here is some javascript and this is using Ember App Kit:

```
var RecipeIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('recipe', this.modelFor('recipe').id);
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        model.reload();
    }
});

export default RecipeIndexRoute;
```

This should get it to make a request to your API on the recipe/:recipe_id endpoint.

Comment: Excellent answer. Only thing I would change is `return this.store.find('recipe', params.recipe_id)` and for me it'd just be `RecipeRoute` with `ember-cli`.